# PHP: foreach loop by id and month and add values

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach

I've been trying to solve this issue I'm currently having. We have a table with `id`, `productid`, `userid`, `count` and `downloaddate`. Something like below to understand the structure and what the results look like.

```
+----+-----------+--------+-------+---------------+
| id | productid | userid | count | downloaddate  |  
+----+-----------+--------+-------+---------------+
|  1 |         9 |    231 |     2 | October 2017   |  
|  2 |         8 |    230 |     1 | October 2017  |  
|  3 |         9 |    287 |     1 | October 2017  |  
|  4 |         9 |    200 |     2 | November 2017 |  
+----+-----------+--------+-------+---------------+
```

So what I want to loop is to get all the `productid` and return the total number of `count` for the given month which is recorded in the `downloaddate` column.

To return this:

```
+------------+-------+---------------+
| productid  | count | downloaddate  |  
+------------+-------+---------------+
|          9 |     3 | October 2017   |  
|          8 |     1 | October 2017  |  
|          9 |     2 | November 2017 |  
+------------+-------+---------------+
```

Is it possible to do this? I've tried this but it's returning the total `count` for the `productid`

```
$sum = array();
$emparray = array();

foreach ($downloads as $download){ 
   $emparray[] = $download;
}


foreach ($emparray as $downloaded){ 
   if (!isset($sum[$downloaded->id])) { 
      $sum[$downloaded->id]['count'] = $downloaded->count;
      $sum[$downloaded->id]['downloaddate'] = $downloaded->downloaddate;
    } else { 
      $sum[$downloaded->id]['count'] += $downloaded->count;
      $sum[$downloaded->id]['downloaddate'] = $downloaded->downloaddate;
     } 
 }
```

Any help will be appreciated!

**EDIT**

This is my sql query:

```
$downloads = $wpdb->get_results( 
             "
                SELECT ast.*, dl.userid, dl.count, dl.downloaddate 
                FROM $lead_table as ast
                JOIN $table_downloads as dl ON (dl.productid = ast.id)
              "
            );
```

Comment: This should be possible to do in only sql though, no need to waste time in PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the result by one query grouping by productid and  downloaddate (I hope that `October2017` is a typo in the question)

```
SELECT productid, sum(count) as count, downloaddate 
   FROM your_table
   GROUP BY productid, downloaddate
```

update. with your query it seems to be

```
SELECT ast.*, dl.userid, sum(dl.count) as count, dl.downloaddate 
    FROM $lead_table as ast
    JOIN $table_downloads as dl 
      ON (dl.productid = ast.id)
    GROUP BY dl.userid, dl.downloaddate
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that I'm using 2 tables to get the data with JOIN. I'll add my SQL query to the question. Will I still be able to use GROUP BY and count()?

Comment: Yes October2017 was a typo. It is inserting the month with date("F Y").

Answer (score 1):

i think you should edit your sql Query into this :

```
SELECT productid, sum(count) as count, downloaddate FROM your_table GROUP BY downloaddate
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that I'm using 2 tables to get the data with JOIN. I'll add my SQL query to the question. Will I still be able to use GROUP BY and count()?

Answer (score 0):

You have to be able to tell which month is given in the downloaddate (can you build a timestamp ? Or something else that tells you that "October2017" is the same that "October 2017".

Once you got that, you "just" have to store your "sum" in a 2D array with something like that:

```
$sum = array();
foreach ($downloads as $download) {
    // dateToTimeStamp: custom function who gives you the same number for October2017 or October 2017
    $timestamp = dateToTimeStamp($downloaded->downloaddate);
    if (!isset($sum[$timestamp])) {
        $sum[$timestamp] = [];
    }

    if (!isset($sum[$timestamp][$downloaded->id])) { 
        $sum[$timestamp][$downloaded->id]['count']        = $downloaded->count;
        $sum[$timestamp][$downloaded->id]['downloaddate'] = $downloaded->downloaddate;

        continue 1;
    }

    $sum[$timestamp][$downloaded->id]['count']       += $downloaded->count;
    $sum[$timestamp][$downloaded->id]['downloaddate'] = $downloaded->downloaddate; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can easily use this query and extract the data from php and use it there

```
 select productid,sum(count),downloaddate from tablename group by productid,downloaddate
```